# Add mailto link to static email with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a mailto link to static email addresses found within a list of results from a database, using JQuery. I was able to find the following excerpt online which works for the first result, but it does not work for any email addresses after the first one.

I'm curious why this is.. and how I can get it to apply the mailto: attribute to every email address found in the results. :-)

Current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;
    $("table td").filter(function() {
        return $(this).html().match(regEx);
    }).each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by first result? only first `td` or only the first email in the td?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific! -- Only the first TD. :-)

Comment: Can you set up a DEMO at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea why it works only for the first match, but you can improve your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/;
    $("table td").filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.match(regEx);
    }).html(function(index, old) {
        return old.replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I attempted to use your code, but it's reporting a syntax error with the following:

"return old.replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>"));"

--

As for my existing code, it appears the Javascript is 'freezing' at some point and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot it since it's not reporting any issues. Basically I have a PHP database returning the results, and the JS is supposed to add links to the email addresses in those results. Unfortunately, even when I add console.log("Message"); after the code I originally used, it doesn't show that. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1364769. Sorry, there were unmatched `(`, anyway, where is the regex from? Give me a demo to work with.

Comment: Hey there!

It works when I tested it on JSFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/xV2HP/

I'm using the same code on my PHP page, but it's odd that only the first result is getting the link. :/ I know this must be difficult to troubleshoot unless I give you access to the admin panel I'm looking at. I was wondering if you had any ideas for me to troubleshoot this further. By the way, the Console is not reporting any errors at all.

Comment: @user1364769. Nope. Good luck. I'm afraid you need to consult with a real person about it, not with an internet shade... :)

Comment: Just wrap this code (excluding document ready) in a $.each function.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it's no more useful for you but maybe could be for someone: you have to add a 'g' at the end of the regexp:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var regEx = /(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/g;
$("table td").filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.match(regEx);
}).html(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(regEx, "<a href=\"mailto:$1\">$1</a>");
});
```

});​

From [W3C School site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp):

> Note: If the regular expression does not include the g modifier (to perform a global search), the match() method will return only the first match in the string.

Comment: I spent a while working on this very issue that the /g solved. There are several other posts regarding this on many of the jquery blog posts regarding converting static emails/urls to links. They all use the regex without the /g. Thanks for this.